# Arduino IDE (Win10) crashes when I launch the program

Tags: windows, arduino, crash, windows-10, arduino-ide

My Arduino IDE (ver 1.8.12 on Win10) crashes when I launch it. Running the `arduino_debug.exe` I get this error message.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino>arduino_debug.exe
Set log4j store directory C:\Users\volke\AppData\Local\Arduino15
Loading configuration...
Initializing packages...
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at cc.arduino.contributions.packages.ContributionsIndexer.parseIndex(ContributionsIndexer.java:134)
        at processing.app.BaseNoGui.initPackages(BaseNoGui.java:483)
        at processing.app.Base.<init>(Base.java:273)
        at processing.app.Base.main(Base.java:150)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino>
```

Any solutions? I've tried to delete the config files `package_index.json` and `package_esp32_index.json` without any luck.

Comment: Same thing here, I think it has something to do with a new package or something. It started today and yes I spend the whole day trying to fix it.

ESP8266 works if you install it as git instead of using boards manager. Problem is vscode extension will not work!

Comment: There is a Github issues about this already here: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/10332

Comment: Seems to be a problem wih packages index, because I've installed older versions that were working on Windows 10, cleaning all the Arduino folders, and all failed. I've also tested the Arduino IDE Beta and seems to work, because at least this version ignores the index errors.

Comment: It's happening in Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) as well.

Comment: @TomServo and other close voters: This is clearly the _IDE_ crashing, not user code. Perhaps the IDE's developers could use advice on how to prevent NPEs in their code, but that's not going to help the IDE's _users_.

Comment: Also crashing for MAC

Comment: It was working fine on my machine as well as two other machine running on Windows 10.
I got windows update on two machine and after that I see that on both machine it stopped working. Looks like something is wrong with IDE after this windows update possibly as it works on windows 7 systems.

Comment: it was a temporary problem. to recover see https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/10341#issuecomment-641836099

Comment: Why did you accept that non relevant dupe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm on Windows 10 having exactly this issue (same arduino_debug log).
I tried uninstalling Arduino IDE and then reinstalling it from executable installer; it worked fine until I opened the Board manager: the problem recurs.

After installing the beta version (arduino beta1.9-BUILD-119), I'm not having any problem.

Answer (score 6):

I've got the same issue - the nightly build seems to work

https://www.arduino.cc/download.php?f=/arduino-nightly-windows.zip

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software

Answer (score 0):

Just use the latest Arduino IDE Beta Version. It is working now, ignoring that issue. I'm using the ESP8266 board and it's running okay.

Answer (score 0):

The **beta** version 1.9 worked for me. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software

Comment: Worked for me as well. Hopefully, the regular build gets fixed as well. Wasted a couple of hours on this.

Answer (score -1):

It also happens on Manjaro linux. In my case removing the folder .arduino15 solves the issue, but I have to remove it every time I open arduino IDE

```
rm -rf ~/.arduino15/
```

Win10 folder location:

```
%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local
```

Comment: Please refrain form posting answers if it's not a well functioning solution, the answer you gave is more of a hack and the OP has in a way already done this. Plus it won't work if you're compiling for other boards like esp32 etc. So, Rather add this as a comment to the question. Thank you :).