# Why the Arduino IDE isn't opening?

Tags: arduino, ide, arduino-ide

The title is self-explanatory. Here is what returns arduino_debug.exe:

```
D:\Arduino>arduino_debug.exe
Set log4j store directory C:\Users\Kiwi\AppData\Local\Arduino15
Loading configuration...
Initializing packages...
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at cc.arduino.contributions.packages.ContributionsIndexer.parseIndex(Con
tributionsIndexer.java:134)
    at processing.app.BaseNoGui.initPackages(BaseNoGui.java:483)
    at processing.app.Base.<init>(Base.java:273)
    at processing.app.Base.main(Base.java:150)
```

D:\Arduino>

PS: I already tried reinstalling the latest version.

Comment: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/10341#issuecomment-641836099

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arduino IDE (Win10) crashes when I launch the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62290881/arduino-ide-win10-crashes-when-i-launch-the-program)

Answer (score -2):

You must delete whole folder **Arduino15** in C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\
I suggest you make backup of folder before delete !

Comment: you must not delete the whole folder. you would lost your settings and all the boards packages. the link I put in comment has the solution. it was a problem for some hours and is fixed. only two files should be deleted to recover.